# IllegalArgumentException: savedInstanceState Specified as Non-Null is Null

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I am getting a strange error when I start my `MainActivity`:

```
06-16 16:01:05.193 2083-2083/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.android.example.github, PID: 2083
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.example.github/com.android.example.github.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
            at com.android.example.github.injection.AppInjector$init$1.onActivityCreated(AppInjector.kt)
            at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:197)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:961)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.java:54)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:319)
            at com.android.example.github.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

This is my `MainActivity` class:

```
class MainActivity : LifecycleActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>
        @Inject set

    lateinit var navigationController: NavigationController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navigationController.navigateToSearch()
        }
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

}
```

The error states that the parameter `savedInstanceState` is null, when it is specified as non-null; but it is nullable (`savedInstanceState: Bundle?`) and the `onCreate()` method is marked as `@Nullable` in the source.

I have not come across this error in any of my other Kotlin projects. I am using Kotlin version 1.1.2-5; and had the same error with 1.1.2-3.

Comment: I have same issue. what is the issue on AppInjector, can you suggest it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the issue isn't in the `onCreate` method. Try looking at `com.android.example.github.injection.AppInjector$init$1.onActivityCreated(AppInjector.kt)`. I can't tell if it's a generated class, but it should give you an idea of what to do next.

Answer (score 70):

I had the exact same problem, you have to make nullable types here:

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(bundle: Bundle?, s: String?) {}
```

Comment: What if i can't able to change this definition? for ex. SDK library functions!

Comment: Thanks! My DialogFragments (converted form java to Kotlin from Android Studio) were crashing and just a simple ? on the Bundle in the `onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog` fixed it!

Comment: Seems like this changes the signature of an inherited function.  I confirmed it works though, no compiler errors.  In what other ways can we change the signature of a function that we override?

Answer (score 19):

The issue is in the AppInjector. I used the google GitHubBrowser sample like you did and ran into this same error. I copied the code over to my project and let Android Studio convert it to Kotlin. When it did this it didn't properly specify the nullability of the `savedInstanceState` parameter which is what is causing the crash. Just make it optional like in the below code and it will work.

```
object AppInjector {
    fun init(app: App) {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(app)
                .build().inject(app)
        app
                .registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
                    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                        handleActivity(activity)
                    }

                    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {

                    }
                })
    }

    private fun handleActivity(activity: Activity) {
        if (activity is HasSupportFragmentInjector) {
            AndroidInjection.inject(activity)
        }
        (activity as? FragmentActivity)?.supportFragmentManager?.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
                object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                    override fun onFragmentCreated(fm: FragmentManager?, f: Fragment?,
                                                   savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                        if (f is Injectable) {
                            AndroidSupportInjection.inject(f)
                        }
                    }
                }, true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You may use null-coalescing operator `?:`. The `savedInstanceState` will be passed to the `super.onCreate` method only if it is `@NonNull`, otherwise, if it is `null`, an empty `Bundle()` will be passed.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState?: Bundle())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer! Would you mind explaining what you are doing in your solution?

Answer (score 2):

As @mcassiano noted, it appears the issue isn't with your `onCreate` method but actually `onActivityCreated`. Two thoughts:

- Due to the fact that libraries and such are in transition, for now you may have to just manually override `onActivityCreated` in your fragment and explicitly mark the Bundle as nullable: `(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`. You shouldn't have to, but manually setting up the nullability may just help.
- I notice that the crash goes all the way down to BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread - is this a result of using the LifecycleActivity? Or do you have other, older, out-of-date dependencies in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You know that inside function `super.onCreate` looks like `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` this saveInstanceState cannot be Null and may be calling function can be connect to orther functions. In my case, `super.onCreate` connects to `onCreatePreferences`then i fixed this problem, this code following to:

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_pomodoro)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState?:Bundle.EMPTY)

    if (context != null) {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context!!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if nothing else works, you can just pass an empty Bundle this way:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
    savedInstanceState = new Bundle();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

or if you always want an empty bundle then simply:

```
super.onCreate(new Bundle());
```

Mayne not so pretty, but works.