# Kotlin : Sign In using google Fails

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin, androidx

I'm getting following error log while executing the google sign in procedure in android code. Using native button instead of google button for sign in process. Completed everything as per the documentation by google. Google documentation link :
[image]

Project gradle : `google()`

app gradle : `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'`

Error Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.myapp/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
    at com.test.myapp.base.MyApplication$setupActivityListener$1.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source:7)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:221)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1071)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:75)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:335)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
```

Code:
   oncreate:

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()

    // Configure Google Sign In Initialization
    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
```

functions :

```
   private fun signIn() {
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        handleSignInResult(task)

    }
}

private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        Log.e(TAG, "Google sign in success : "+account!!)

    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Google sign in failed")
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
    }

}
```

Code from MyApplication class:

```
 private fun setupActivityListener() {
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
        override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}
        override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
            activeActivity = activity
        }

        override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
            activeActivity = null
        }

        override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {}
        override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {}
        override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {}
    })
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Post your code for google signin as well..

Comment: show me your code..

Comment: sure , i'll update

Comment: maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597348/illegalargumentexception-savedinstancestate-specified-as-non-null-is-null

Comment: @P.Juni checked that one, not useful

Comment: show me the code of this variable googleSignInClient

Comment: @SARATHV in your code `savedInstanceState` is null. Check where are you using that. And share the code if possible.

Comment: savedInstanceState of SignInHubActivity right? i think, its an internal activtity. if the savedInstanceState of current activity is null, evreything inside activity has to be crahed right? sorry if i'm wrong @PrithviBhola

Comment: hi @SARATHV show me the code of this variable googleSignInClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crashlog it looks that you have parameter `savedInstanceState` mark as non-null but it can be nullable. Maybe you should check `setupActivityListener` method in `MyApplication` class.

Comment: Method with parameter like this: `savedInstanceState: Bundle` instead `savedInstanceState: Bundle?`

Comment: can you check my updated question.. setupActivityListener included.

Comment: Are you getting the same exception with `override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}`?